# navigate to DOM element in jQuery and assign to variable

Tags: jquery, dom, navigation

I'm developing a WordPress theme and built the [Fancybox lightbox plugin](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#news) into my code. This works fine, except from one tiny problem.

But I'll show you the code first, so it is easier to explain.

```
<dl class='gallery-item'>
    <dt class='gallery-icon'>
        <a href='image.jpg' title='something'><img width="150" height="150" src="image.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" title="something" /></a>
    </dt>
    <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
        Description, that should be displayed as title...
    </dd>
</dl>
```

This is the output of one gallery item of the WordPress standard gallery. What I want to do, is attaching the description in the dd-tags to the lightbox image title (at ht emoment the title of the a-tag is being displayed and that is an alphanumeric string - not very user friendly).

In order to assign something to the lightbox title, the following javascript has to be called in the initialization-function of the lightbox. (This code actually assigns the content of the first *.wp-caption-text* element to every single image title.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({

    beforeLoad: function(){
        var caption = $('.wp-caption-text').html();
        this.title = caption;
        }
    });
});
```

The above code works as expected, but this means, that only the first element with the class *wp-caption-text* will be assigned to the lightbox and to every single image. But I want to get only the respective *wp-caption-text* for the image, that has been opened in the lightbox. So I will have to use something like *$(this)* and then navigate to the corresponding *wp-caption-text* and assign the text to the *caption* variable.

I'm struggling with the last point and hope, you can help me. This should not be too difficult, but I don't have a clue at the moment.

Thanks
Lukas

Comment: can you show us all of the code that initializes the lightbox? im guessing it happens on a click event?

Comment: I added the whole init code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be stable if the markup changes. If this doesn't work it means that `this` isn't quite what we expect it to be and we need to figure out what it is. Also notice that I'm using  `.text()` instead of `.html()`. If you decide to add some markup inside of `.wp-capition-text`  (for example, an icon or something), this will still just grab the text.

```
var caption = $(this.element).closest('.gallery-item').find('.wp-caption-text').text();
```

Comment: Doesn't work. But as you see in my comment above `this` seems to refer to the a-tag and `$(this.element)` to the image as it's child. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: could you please do a `alert(caption)` to see if its what you expect? I'm wondering if you are supposed to set it something other than `this.title`.

Comment: Got it work now with `var caption = $(this.element).closest('.gallery-item').find('.wp-caption-text').html();`. So `$(this.element)` is the anchor. But thanks for your advice, works very well now. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var caption =  $(this).parent().parent().find('.wp-caption-text').html();
```

This is if **this**  corresponds to the current anchor

Comment: I always avoid `.parent().parent()` chains because they break if the markup changes. I'd go with `$(this).closest('.gallery-item')` instead.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I'm not exactly shure, if `this refers to the anchor, but neither 1x or 3x .parent() work. So it seems to be a bit tricky.

Comment: I found out, that `var caption = $(this.element).html();` displays the current image again in the title area.

Comment: So try this then $(this.element).parent().parent().find('.wp-caption-text').html();

Comment: Also check what the output is by writing it to the console

Comment: Hi, as you see above, it is already working. ;) You might have a look at the result: http://projects.lb-home.de/2012/08/vorstellung-meiner-werkstatt/ (my site is in German, but the effect should become clear)

Comment: I meant was to debug what this $(this.element).parent().parent() turns out to be in the console